# In Vim what command will put the cursor at the last character in a file, not the last line?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I realize that `G` will move the cursor to the last line in a file, but is there a command that will move to the last character?
I know I can type `G$` to do this but I thought there might be a single command which does this.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before, and no single-keypress command was listed, though you might prefer `Ctrl-End` to `G$`:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30761/how-to-move-to-last-character-of-the-file-in-vim

Comment: Ah.  I searched SuperUser but I didn't search Unix and Linux. Thanks.  I guess I should always start my searches at StackExchange.com.  There are so many StackExchange sites you never know where an answer might pop up.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a command, the obscure `go` (go to {count} byte), but you have to specify a count >= the file size (e.g. `99999go`), which makes it kinda impractical.